# 1080x1080 photos via Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

http://www.theverge.com/2015/7/6/8899807/instagram-1080p-pictures-photo-upload

The Verge recently made known the latest app versions of Instagram are uploading photos in 1080x1080 resolution. These photos can be easily sourced via HTML when browsing the site's source code. Can these be accessed via the official Instagram API? And if so, how?

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes?

Comment: Adam for the time being please consider marking @sebastien.b's answer the correct one.

Comment: For anyone reading the comments below: Be aware that the 1080 version is usually *not* the biggest version available. IG seems to only make the bigger versions available to their app for whatever reason.

Answer (score 23):

**[Update] After Mar 23, 2018**

I used Ekrem Gurdal's answer to make it work:

The IG API gives you "link" attribute, e.g. https://www.instagram.com/p/BTduOwSAwN6/

Then you can append ?__a=1 to this e.g. https://www.instagram.com/p/BTduOwSAwN6/?__a=1

And you can extract from the json result where the high resolution photo is stored: *graphsql.shortcode_media.display_url*

E.g. https://instagram.fmnl2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/f8f54b9fcb2bca69d7c73d9ffb232d64/5C324A1C/t51.2885-15/e35/18161146_397673830625587_2385146908864675840_n.jpg

Hope this helps. Maybe IG folks will also find a way to disable this in the future. Why do they not just include the hi-res photo in the API response, smh

**[Update] As of Mar 23, 2018, workaround below doesn't work anymore.**

Just to update anyone who's looking at this in 2018. The solution that worked for me is to remove the "vp/" on top of replacing the resolution to 1080x1080.

E.g.

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/41d5aee08758061976d26e48f45e673a/5ADA338E/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/20065394_1785212551507111_5192354829363576832_n.jpg
```

to

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/41d5aee08758061976d26e48f45e673a/5ADA338E/t51.2885-15/s1080x1080/e35/20065394_1785212551507111_5192354829363576832_n.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks Manny, you saved my life 8-)

Comment: Well only for a while - now we get a 400 trying to use this workaround... Thanks everyone at Instagram/Facebook for your unstable, unsupported and uselessly restricted APIs, you make my life so much memorable :-/

Comment: This has been also patched, returns "Access Denied" now.

Comment: Confirmed this and the other updated workarounds, no longer work.

Comment: Updated answer that works when the pre-Mar23 workaround stopped working

Comment: from where we get IMAGE-CODE ?

Comment: Downvoted. No longer works as of March 2019, you get "URL format mismatch" error.

Answer (score 15):

Not sure why you are getting down-voted, but no, that resolution is not returned by the API at the moment. However, it can be "guessed" from the other resolutions returned by the API, but that could change at any time. For example, given the standard resolution JSON:

```
  "standard_resolution": {
    "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e35/sh0.08/11370971_837216559694773_771634899_n.jpg",
    "width": 640,
    "height": 640
  }
```

Remove the size part (`s640x640` here) and the two paths that follows (`e35/sh0.08` for this picture, likely different for yours) to end up with the URL to the `1080x1080`:

```
    https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/11370971_837216559694773_771634899_n.jpg
```

This has worked since that resolution was activated on my account. But again, I would just wait for the API.

Comment: Indeed, this now results in an "Invalid URL signature" 403 HTTP error being return by Instagram

Comment: @dstj Have you found a workaround. Noticed that it stopped working for me as well.

Comment: Downvoted. Does not work as of March 2019, you get "URL format mismatch".

Answer (score 9):

As of 26th March 2018, Instagram changed their links.
Here's a working solution to get 1080x1080 resolution images from API.

1. Get the user_Id from `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1`.
2. Paste the user_id in this link `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/{user_id}/info/`.
3. Get the hd url link from `hd_profile_pic_url_info`. :)

Comment: Are you using IG API? because I can't find and HQ links in their API response.

Comment: @user1945821 - Just copy the user_id from the first link and paste that in the second link. In the api response from the second link you can get all the links related to profile picture.

Comment: Haa ok, I was looking for user's media (pictures) not profile picture. And they return only thumbnail, low_resolution, standard_resolution. no hd or any high resolution

Comment: The 2nd link is broken, it redirects to the login page of Instagram instead of returning JSON. Why?

Comment: Upvoted. As of 27th March 2019 this is the only solution that worked for me. All the others give me either "access denied" or "URL structure mismatch".

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that simply removing the size part, the biggest image is returned:

> https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e35/sh0.08/11370971_837216559694773_771634899_n.jpg

to

> https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/e35/sh0.08/11370971_837216559694773_771634899_n.jpg

Hence this should do the trick:

```
var hightUrl = data.images.standard_resolution.url.replace("/s640x640/","/");
```

Comment: "URL signature expired" - this one would have been nice too!! :|

Comment: Not sure if the SO policy is to delete no more valid responses.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply fetch 1080p image if available by using this url:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/['IMAGE-CODE']/?__a=1
```

[image: Different size of an image]

Comment: from where we get IMAGE-CODE ?

Comment: it's the shortcode, however this doesn't work for private images if you only have an access token. I cannot seem to get it not to respond 404.

Comment: @AshokDevatwal I mean that link of the post. Here is a json of my post: https://www.instagram.com/p/BhWLTrklsfH/?__a=1 You can find the link of 1080p picture in 29th line.

Comment: in 2021 this still works, the third seems to be the original image that was uploaded.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with instagram image URL's is that the URL signatures provided in the json responses expire after some time. My workaround for this problem is as follows:

Steps:
1. Get the instagram post link. Eg : https://www.instagram.com/p/Bo-Jru-g7Wa/

or if you don't have the link, the instagram api provides you with a permalink(image-code) option in the result array which for the above link is **Bo-Jru-g7Wa**

2. Now just add **media?size=l** after the url ie.,

**Result**: High quality image url:

https://www.instagram.com/p/Bo-Jru-g7Wa/media?size=l

you can see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/nmj1z7wo/`fiddle URL`

This link can be considered as a shorthand code to instagram image URL's which are very much bigger. Supported values for size are t (thumbnail), m (medium), l (large). Defaults to m.

Comment: `media?size=l` will be the 1080 version max even if bigger versions exist.

Comment: Yes and I think that should be sufficient for most of the use-cases. also you don't have to recreate the image urls every some hours(fb recreates hex codes every 24 to 72 hrs) if you use the above solution.

Comment: any way of fetching higher quality pictures than 1080? I tried putting media?size=xl - it didn't work

Comment: @DarkestOne the max available is 1080 version as instagram compresses the images internally after you upload them. So max you can get is size=l

Comment: I can regularly find 1440x1800 version of picture on many profiles. For instance on https://www.instagram.com/p/CcwARWxv2jS - developer tools under src attribute there is 1440x1800 version of picture

Comment: @DarkestOne you will see a cache key attached there. The key used to expires daily(I currently don't know the time to expire but it will expire in some time). After the key expires you can't see the image as the link won't show you the image. My answer to this question is only option I was able to find to retrieve the image every time.

Answer (score 1):

This works as of 20th March 2018.

Remove the vp and the size parts.
So if we have a 150x150 image [here](https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/6f28b299faab04675a936073c94d0fde/5B2E3498/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c135.0.810.810/28152308_875888592619569_7505395194448052224_n.jpg)

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/6f28b299faab04675a936073c94d0fde/5B2E3498/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c135.0.810.810/28152308_875888592619569_7505395194448052224_n.jpg
```

Remove /vp and /s150x150 to get

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/6f28b299faab04675a936073c94d0fde/5B2E3498/t51.2885-15/e35/c135.0.810.810/28152308_875888592619569_7505395194448052224_n.jpg
```

And we can get the 1080 image
[here](https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/6f28b299faab04675a936073c94d0fde/5B2E3498/t51.2885-15/e35/c135.0.810.810/28152308_875888592619569_7505395194448052224_n.jpg)

You can even just leave the last two segments

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/e35/28152308_875888592619569_7505395194448052224_n.jpg
```

which can be seen [here](https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/e35/28152308_875888592619569_7505395194448052224_n.jpg)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me today (15 August 2018) for ***most*** public images. I think, because people use different apps to upload images, the API may show different sizes but the links are to the same default resolution file.

1. Go to the user's page: https://www.instagram.com/`username`
2. Click on the image you want and the URL bar will change to: https://www.instagram.com/p/`image-code`/?taken-by=`username`
3. Copy the `image-code` from the URL
4. Go to: https://www.instagram.com/p/`image-code`/?__a=1
5. Scan through the JSON file (it helps to have a [JSON viewer extension](https://www.google.com/search?q=JSON%20viewer%20extension) enabled) and click on the highest resolution image to download it. For example:

[image]

Comment: Is it still working. i want to get hd_profile_pic_url_info. Is it possible anyhow?

Comment: @Awadesh Yes, I used it just last week.

Comment: Actually i want to get this data on server side for my android app. I have no platform where user will click on the image. Could you please suggest something

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether it's possible to get a 1080p resolution image. But here is one way to get an image with `320x320` resolution.

1) Enter the `username` of the user in the following URL. Here I'm using `simonsterstrength` as username.
  https://www.instagram.com/simonsterstrength/?__a=1

2) Search for `"profile_pic_url_hd"` and copy the URL and access the picture that IG calls it as HD.

---

Note: As of June-2020, the response from IG CDN is OK.

Answer (score -1):

You received

```
"standard_resolution": {
    "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e35/sh0.08/11370971_837216559694773_771634899_n.jpg",
    "width": 640,
    "height": 640
  }
```

It's possible to replace `s640x640` with `s1080x1080` or `2048x2048`. Both this request return image with resolut  **1080x1080**

```
var hightUrl = data.images.standard_resolution.url.replace("s640x640","s1080x1080");
```

Comment: Nice use of my own example code to write essentially the same answer :)

Comment: It's not the same anwer... both return a different image. The one from the example of sebastien.b returns the real 1080 resolution picture, if availible. The answer of Dmitry returns an upscaled version of the 640x640 image. This one is bigger, almost 100KB and the quality is clearly less then the original 1080 one.