# How to view instagram profile picture in full-size?

Tags: instagram, profile-picture

I was able to view and download a person's full sized, high resolution profile picture on Instagram until even a few days ago. I usually remove the 's150x150' from the URL and it worked fine for me. But now when I try the same thing I get a error saying 'Invalid URL signature'. I don't know what's happened. Can someone find me a solution for this problem? Or an alternate method maybe?

Comment: Presumably, Instagram changed an undocumented implementation detail. Not much you can do except for looking for a different hack if that's not covered by their API.

Comment: https://scontent-vie1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/something/something/t51.2885-19/s150x150/something.jpg -> https://scontent-vie1-1.cdninstagram.com/something/something/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/something.jpg ; I removed "vp/" , replaced "t51.2885-19" with "t51.2885-15" i.e. "-19"->"-15" and replaced "s150x150/" with "sh0.08/e35/"

Comment: See Anyone's Instagram Profile Picture At Full Size at https://instadp.org/ by just entering a username of the user

Comment: Use this link http://insta-downloader.net/profile-picture

Answer (score 21):

replace "150x150" with 720x720 and remove /vp/ from the link.it should work.

Comment: No need for 720x720, the additional step now is to not only remove the "s640x640/" part but also "vp/" part as well, and it will now give the original image again. Thanks, fahad!

Comment: After removing s640x640/ part, we get Invalid URL Signature error

Comment: Same result as Prateek

Comment: its not working:?

Comment: @tayfun Instagram changed their links. No it is not working. "Access denied"

Comment: @Marcel1997 - Get the user_Id from `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1` and get the profile pic url from `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/{user_id}/info/` :)

Comment: @GaneshMunisifreddy Your method works, but only up to 320x320. Is there any method to get 1080x1080 like you used to get?

Comment: @HugoDaBosss It also works for 1080p images. Anyways try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49490518/5819858).

Comment: Some private profiles don't have hd in the `/info/`  I found this website that works though. http://insta-downloader.net/

Comment: They just changed it. It now says `access denied`.

Comment: There is no "150x150" or any other numbers with x in betwenn in the url I see...

Comment: it doesn't work any more

Comment: http://insta-downloader.net/profile-picture . Boom

Comment: @Marcel1997 you should post it as a answer, because it should be the accepted one :)

Answer (score 7):

You can even set the prof. pic size to its high resolution that is '1080x1080'

replace "150x150" with 1080x1080 and remove /vp/ from the link.

Comment: Instagram changed their links. No it is not working. "Access denied"

Comment: any development about "access denied" ?

Comment: there is no "150x150" in the picture URL i have in my profile... (which i use for teseting this)

Comment: still now working

Comment: Try to use external pages like http://izuum.com