# Is there a way to get images from Instagram API bigger than 1080x1080px?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We are building a print on demand app based on user images and are looking into the best quality image we can get.
Right now, it looks the best we can get from API is 1080x1080.
Is there any way to get them bigger?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1080x1080 photos via Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302811/1080x1080-photos-via-instagram-api) - note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296606/1270789) gives the latest method.