# How to get Instagram story highlights cover photo in HD

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to access the cover photo of an Instagram story highlight in its full size. I'm not sure if this is accessible through the Instagram API but I'm assuming there will be a similar solution to the one used for profile pictures ([1080x1080 photos via Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302811/1080x1080-photos-via-instagram-api/49490518#49490518)).

Here's a public story highlight cover photo from Instagram's official page: https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/4ed116247dc101eb2268d44fa7a672dd/5D231F06/t51.12442-15/e15/c0.280.720.720a/s150x150/38291305_273562119909817_4197279119550971904_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com

Unfortunately you can't just remove 's150x150' anymore or you'll get an access denied error or URL signature mismatch. Is it at all possible?